# Is there a way I can extract table data from a SQL database without using the ResultSet class in Java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am programming a fairly simple database application in Java.  The typical way of extracting data from a SQL database goes something like this:

```
    private Connection conn = null;
    private Statement stmt = null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?" + "user=monty&password=greatsqldb");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT foo FROM bar");
    rs.first();
    int firstColumn = getInt(1);
    String secondColumnn = getString(2);
```

My problem is that [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) lacks a lot of functionality that I want (for instance a getRow() method that would return the whole row or a getNumberOfRows() method that would tell me how many rows are in the ResultSet).  I could code these myself, but I have a feeling that someone else already has.

Does anyone know of an class that provides these methods and other useful functionality?

No offense to anyone who loves the ResultSet class.

Comment: `ResultSet` is the part of the JDBC API which is the lowest level you can use for interacting with SQL type databases in Java. You can use a wrapper for the additional functionality you are looking for, but internally, a `ResultSet` is most likely being used.

Comment: I'll google for a wrapper that works.  Is there one that you can suggest?

Comment: Look into Spring JDBC Template. It removes many of the burdens of JDBC without introducing the problems of an ORM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into an appropriate ORM such as hibernate or JPA.  These will allow you to interact with the DB through objects and their OO links (compositions, lists, sets, etc).

http://www.hibernate.org/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to accomplish your task only with plain vanilla JDBC, then I would say no.
Data access can be classified into two categories.

1. **Connected  architecture**
   Your ResultSet falls under this.
2. **Disconnected architecture**
   CachedRowSet falls under this.

The above answer might not be directly related to your query but this will be helpful for your understanding. You can also think of using ORM(hibernate,JPA,[MyBatis](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyBatis)) for more Object-oriented approach of data access functionality. It has many advantage over JDBC.

Hope this will be helpful

Cheers!

Comment: The ORMs use JDBC underneath so no magic added. The ORMs can provide many features but not anything more than you could technically do yourself writing JDBC.  The original question was about getting access to data without ResultSet, but ORMs will be using the same ResultSet.